# How to get the first day of a given week number in PHP (multi-platform)?

Tags: php

What is the simplest way to do it in PHP ?

I want the date of the Monday of a given week number of a year (example : week number 3 of 2009)

Thanks !

EDIT : If you use Linux only machines, use cletus' solution, however I am looking for something that can work on Windows AND Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
<?php
        $week = 3;
        $year = 2009;

        $timestamp = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  $year ) + ( $week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
        $timestamp_for_monday = $timestamp - 86400 * ( date( 'N', $timestamp ) - 1 );
        $date_for_monday = date( 'Y-m-d', $timestamp_for_monday );
?>
```

Comment: This is the simplest working solution to date on both my Linux and Windows platforms.

Comment: `date( 'U', $timestamp )` could be shortened to `$timestamp`.

Comment: Updated as per deceze's suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't work for Years where the Monday of the first Week is in the previous Year, for example: $week=1; $year=2013.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have `$week=40`. Returned date is in 41th week of the year...

Comment: This will be a problem with DST changes, because a week will not have 86400 seconds

Answer (score 56):

It's simple on PHP 5.3

```
echo date('M d',strtotime('2013W15'));
```

where 15 is the number of week. But for the number below ten make sure it is in the format of 01, 02 for first week and second week.

Comment: I dont see any problem using this with PHP 5.2 or 5.1 either. Worked great for me and I am using 5.2.18 I think. Thanks for this shortcut!

Comment: This solution actually works way better than the dateobject. Have found the dateobject to be way too cumbersome in many situations. Hence this is the way to go!

Comment: Tip: In case your week number is < 10, make sure to use W05 (for the 5th week) and not W5. So: `date('M d', strtotime('2022W05'));`

Answer (score 11):

A nice way to get this in a clean way is by using php DateTime class.

```
$year = 2015;
$week_no = 1;

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($year,$week_no);
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

This would result into : 29-12-2014

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strptime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to get the time.

```
$time = strptime('1 23 2009', '%w %U %Y');
```

This will get the time for the Monday (day 1, 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday) of the 23rd week of 2009. If you want to format this into a date, use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$date = date('d F Y', $time);
```

Comment: Yea, says in the notes of the PHP.net page: no-worky on Windows.

Comment: In PHP >= 5.3, it seems the DateTime object contains this functionality, on windows as well. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2):

This next script gives the 7 days of an specific week of a year

```
$time = new DateTime();
$time->setISODate(2016, 13);
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    echo $time->format('d-M-Y') . '<br />';
    $time->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working and not dependent of the server OS :

```
<?php

  $week = 4;
  $year = 2013;

  $timestamp_for_monday = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  $year ) + ((7+1-(date( 'N', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  $year ) )))*86400) + ($week-2)*7*86400 + 1 ;

?>
```

the idea is to add :

- the timestamp of the first of January of the chosen year
- the number of seconds to reach the end of the first week (which is 7 days minus the day of week of the 1st of January + 1 day) multiplied by the number of seconds per day
- the number of seconds of the number of chosen weeks minus the first week and the current week
- 1 second to reach the fist second of the current week

My example returns : 1358722801
which is the timestamp of 2013/01/21 0:00:01

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple solution, passing a week no and returns the date.

The ISO8601 standard states that week 1 always fall on the week where Jan 4 falls.

For example, to get a day in the 4th week of the year:

```
$day_in_week = strtotime("2006-01-04 + 4 weeks"));
```

Then you can adjust this value to Sunday (as a starting place you can guarantee that you can find):

```
// Find that day's day of the week (value of 0-6)
$wday = date('w', $day_in_week);
$offset = 6 - $wday; // How far it is from Sunday.
$sunday_in_week = $day_in_week - ($offset * (60 * 60 * 24)); // $offset * seconds in a day
```

Then, you add the seconds in a day again to get Monday.

```
$monday_in_week = $sunday_in_week + (60 * 60 * 24);
```

**Note:** This method can occasionally have some problems with daylight savings time.  A similar, and slightly safer between DST time changes, method would use [the DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).  However, DateTime is only support in PHP 5.2.0 or later.  The method above works in earlier version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function MondayOfWeek($WeekNumber, $Year=-1) {
    if ($Year == -1) $Year   = 0+date("Y");
    $NewYearDate             = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$Year);
    $FirstMondayDate         = 7 + 1 - date("w", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2009));
    $Dates_fromFirstMonday   = 7 * $WeekNumber;
    $Second_fromFirstMonday  = 60*60*24*($FirstMondayDate + $Dates_fromFirstMonday);
    $MondayDay_ofWeek        = $NewYearDate + $Second_fromFirstMonday;
    $Date_ofMondayDay_ofWeek = 0+date("j", $MondayDay_ofWeek);
    return $Date_ofMondayDay_ofWeek;
}

for($i = 0; $i
```

When run, I got:

```
-5-12-19-26-2-9-16-23-2-9-16-23-30-6-13-20-27-4-11-18-25-1-8-15-22-29-6-13-20-27-3-10-17-24-31-7-14-21-28-5-12-19-26-2-9-16-23-30-7-14-21-28
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I required same in the java script..so i converted.

```
function(week,year){
var timestamp = new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var dateObj=new Date();
var val = timestamp.getTime(); 
days=( week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60*1000 );
val=val+days;
var timestamp_for_monday =val - 86400 *((timestamp.getDay()-1000));
var weekdate=new Date(timestamp_for_monday);
return weekdate;
}
```