# Get first day date of the week on a given date PHP

Tags: php, symfony, date

I have a date `2015-12-16`

i want to get the date of the first day's date for the current week of my date

here `2015-12-16` is in the week 51 of the year then i want to get the first day's date of the week 51 ( `2015-12-14` here)

how could i do it ?
thank you

EDIT: it must work when there are 53 weeks in the year (like in 2015 for example)

Comment: Could you share your code with us?

Comment: [Google would've done the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

Comment: @RobFos don't have working code

Comment: @TV it's not what i want i want to do it with a given date

Comment: Working code or not you should add it.. This is the point of SO rather than asking us to find you code or coding something up

Comment: @Option i won't post code which do absolutely not what i want it won't help someone, including you. If i post this thread it's because i already tried but didn't succeed

Comment: You've clearly missed the point of this place. With this being said I am leaving now,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first day of a given week number in PHP (multi-platform)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659551/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-a-given-week-number-in-php-multi-platform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 $dateTime = new DateTime("2015-12-16");

 $weekNo = $dateTime->format("W");

 $newDate = new DateTime();
 $newDate->setISODate($dateTime->format("Y"), $weekNo);
```

Example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/281a1ac298bfee8be421e333e4b7e92c6bb44d65

Since the above is a bit off in some cases here's something more reliable:

```
 $dateTime = new DateTime("2016-01-01");
 $dateTime->sub(new DateInterval("P".($dateTime->format("w")-1)."D"));  //Since the weekdays are 1-based.
```

Example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5cb0f077fa77974d977ddbffa6bc0b61f9d7851

Comment: i'm testing it. Will keep you in touch

Comment: @RomMer keep in mind that weeks start from Monday when using this code.

Comment: yes saw that but it's what i need i just have a last problem
it works weird on 2016 
the first 3 days of january 2016 are actually in the 53th week of 2015 
how could i manage that ?

Comment: i would like for these 3 days that the code gives me the beginning of the 53th week, then 2015-12-28

Comment: @RomMer try the second variation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = new \DateTime('2015-12-16');
echo $date->modify('last sunday +1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
```

This gets start of this week if you count monday to sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('This week', strtotime('2015-12-16')));
```